# Is there a way to draw curves using degree changing?

Tags: java, processing, drawing, curve, degrees

I dont need no real commands or methods, I only wanna know how can i build a for/while loop where I can draw a curve with. I can draw already and I just do not know how to draw a curve using degree changing.

For example:

for(int x = 0; x != 30; x++)

here is missing the part which changes the value of the degree turning.

Comment: the x is the variable for how many points the compiler should draw and the degree variable is missing here because i dont know how to do it properly

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to guess what you mean by

> curve using degree changing

as there are many ways to draw curves

Assuming `x` is your angle in degrees you can easily draw an [arc()](https://processing.org/reference/arc_.html):

```
size(900,900);
noFill();

for(int x = 0; x != 30; x++){
  // optional: visualise angle/arc as a grayscale stroke
  stroke(map(x,0,29,255,0));
  // render an arc at the current angle: notice the angle is in radians
  // args: x, y, width, height, startAngle, stopAngle, arcType
  arc(450, 450, 810, 810, 0, radians(x), PIE);
}
```

There are other types of curves Processing supports: check out the bezier and curve functions (e.g. [`bezierPoint()`](https://processing.org/reference/bezierPoint_.html), [`curvePoint()`](https://processing.org/reference/curvePoint_.html))